# Problem with structure and organization in big c++ project

Tags: c++, header-files, declaration, circular-dependency

I started my first big c++ project, in which I divided the functionality of the program into different files. I ran in a situation where library include each other and there was some declaration problem.

sometingh like this:

*in apha.h*

```
#pagma once
#include "betha.h"

struct alpha
{
    int data;
    betha bb;
};

int fun1(apha a);
```

*in betha.h*

```
#pagma once
#include "alpha.h"

struct betha
{
    double data;
    double moreData;
};

int fun2(alpha a, betha b);
```

I found a solution in transferring all the struct in a separate file *struct.h* and it works fine.
but I was wondering if there was a way to have the struct in their respective libraries
because it would make more sense and be easier to work with.

Comment: There are many methods to solve this, forward declarations are one of the mostly used method. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-build-errors-due-to-circular-dependency-amongst-classes

Comment: Such circular dependency in code is indication of bad code design.

Comment: typo? `apha.h` vs `#include "alpha.h"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters it seems there are two typos in the header name

```
apha.h
```

that should be

```
alpha.h
```

and in this declaration

```
int fun1(apha a);
```

It seems you mean

```
int fun1(alpha a);
```

After including the header `apha.h` in a compilation unit you in fact have

```
struct betha
{
    double data;
    double moreData;
};

int fun2(alpha a, betha b);

struct alpha
{
    int data;
    betha bb;
};

int fun1(apha a);
```

As you can see the function `func2` refers to the name `alpha`

```
int fun2(alpha a, betha b);
```

that was not yet declared.

You could use either the forward declaration

```
struct betha
{
    double data;
    double moreData;
};

struct alpha;

int fun2(alpha a, betha b);
```

or the elaborated type specifier in the function declaration

```
struct betha
{
    double data;
    double moreData;
};

int fun2( struct alpha a, betha b);
```